# The code do not go to the next page and and it doesn't scan the page again, it just scans the first page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
def texto(arquivo):    
    div_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[contains(@class, 'txt_base_b_l') or contains(@class, 'txt_base_n_l') or contains(@class, 'txt_11_b_l')] | //div/b | div")
    # Verificar se os elementos possuem as classes
    for i in range(len(div_elements)):
        current_class = div_elements[i].get_attribute("class")
        current_element = div_elements[i].get_attribute("id")
        
        if current_class == "txt_base_b_l" or current_class == "txt_base_n_l":
            text_elements.append(div_elements[i])
            if current_element ==  "f5_cspm":
                break  # Parar a verificação quando encontrar a classe "footer_outrasligacoes"

    time.sleep(5)
    # Imprimir o conteúdo dos elementos intercalados
    for element in  text_elements:
        content = element.text
        print(content)
        arquivo.write(content + "\n")

def pagina(intercalated_elements, arquivo):
    # Escanear os elementos da página
    div_element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//font")

    # Verificar se os elementos possuem as classes
    for i in range(len(div_element) - 21, len(div_element) - 1):
        element = div_element[i]
        if element.text.isdigit() and 1 <= int(element.text) <= 100:
            intercalated_elements.append(element)

def pagina_seguinte(intercalated_elements, arquivo):
    global continuar_loop
    try:
        texto(arquivo)
        # Verificar de -19 a -1
        for paginas in range(-19, 0):
            print(paginas)
            texto(arquivo)
            time.sleep(5)
            intercalated_elements[paginas].click()
            time.sleep(5)
            pagina(intercalated_elements, arquivo)

        # Verificar de -19 a -1
        for paginas in range(-4, 0):
            texto(arquivo)
            intercalated_elements[paginas].click()
            time.sleep(5)
            pagina(intercalated_elements, arquivo)
            
        # Último elemento da lista
        intercalated_elements[-1].click()
        time.sleep(5)
        pagina(intercalated_elements, arquivo)

    #except StaleElementReferenceException:
        #pagina(intercalated_elements)
        #print('Elemento HTML não encontrado', StaleElementReferenceException)
        #continuar_loop = False
    finally:
        continuar_loop = False

with open("informacoes.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as arquivo:
    
    intercalated_elements = []
    
    text_elements = []
    texto(arquivo)
    pagina(intercalated_elements, arquivo)  # Chamada inicial da função pagina()
    
    continuar_loop = True

    while continuar_loop:
        pagina_seguinte(intercalated_elements, arquivo)

    pagina(intercalated_elements, arquivo)  # Chamada final da função pagina()

    # Fechar o arquivo
    arquivo.close()

# Fechar o console do driver
driver.close()

# Encerra o driver do Selenium
driver.quit()
```

I tried to change the function called inside the for, but nothing changed.

`def pagina_seguinte(intercalated_elements, arquivo):
global continuar_loop
try:
texto(arquivo)
# Verificar de -19 a -1
for paginas in range(-19, 0):
print(paginas)
texto(arquivo)
time.sleep(5)
intercalated_elements[paginas].click()
time.sleep(5)
pagina(intercalated_elements, arquivo)

```
    # Verificar de -19 a -1
    for paginas in range(-4, 0):
        texto(arquivo)
        intercalated_elements[paginas].click()
        time.sleep(5)
        pagina(intercalated_elements, arquivo)
        
    # Último elemento da lista
    intercalated_elements[-1].click()
    time.sleep(5)
    pagina(intercalated_elements, arquivo)
```

`

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)